# SQLAlchemy mysql cannot get the correct charset

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Python 3.8.8 programm with Flask 2.0.1 and Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1

MySql database, collation of the tables: utf8_general_ci.
I'm using two other sqlserver DB with SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. Everything runs on Windows 10.

Some chars from select queries on the MySql DB comes wrong:   "situazione **Ã¨** decisamente migliorata"
should be:              "situazione **è** decisamente migliorata"

This would solve the problem:

> mystring.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')

but I need a solution at program level. I tried:

- appending to SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI connection string:
  "?charset=utf8" or "?charset=cp1215" and others
- setting app.config['MYSQL_CHARSET'] and
  app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CHARSET'] to 'utf8', 'utf8mb4', 'latin1', 'cp1252'
  ...
- passing a parameter to SQLAlchemy like db = SQLAlchemy(use_native_unicode="utf8"), many variations here too

No attemp worked. Please I need suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the issue is? You may be decoding incorrectly into your 'print' or w/e you're using to see the difference here. There are likely a few other places where the encoding could be getting mixed up.

Comment: Yes, ablsolutely sure. I can read the wrong chars in the result of the select query with pycharm's debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

The problem was not a problem.
The person who build the original database (that is quite old) coded wrong some characters.
Some of my approaches and the one suggested by olegsv, worked, I checked that debugging deep down into into sqlalchemy data structures, the driver accepted the characters encoding, but the very chars in data were themself worong.
This was unespected.
Maybe I should delete the whole question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a way to specify per database connection encoding ?

For all connections try to use

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'encoding': 'cp1252'}
```

For specific connections to different DBs you can also use `engine_options`:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@hostname/dbname',
                            encoding='cp1252')
```